# Linq C# linq group by into query differs of result the query in SQL

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, linq

this is my first post here. I appreciate all the help you can give me.

Right now I'm trying to do a query using Linq but i notice that result is wrong. I did the same query using SQL over the table in the database and the result have a little difference.

This is the SQL Query

```
select [Categoria_H], count(*) as conteo
FROM TR_Movimientos
WHERE [TipoPago_H] <> 'Evasor' 
AND [TipoCliente_H] <> 'Evasor' 
AND [TipoPago_H] <> 'Exento'
group by [Categoria_H]
```

This is the Linq Query (2 versions)

1st

```
var qTraficoXCategoria = from reg in registrosDiarios 
where 
   reg.TipoPago_H != GlobalParams.TR_Tipo_Pago_Homologado_Evasor &&
   reg.TipoPago_H != GlobalParams.TR_Tipo_Pago_Homologado_Exento &&
   reg.TipoCliente_H != GlobalParams.TR_Tipo_Cliente_Homologado_Evasor
group reg by reg.Categoria_H into Agrupacion
select new
{ 
   CodigoCategoria = Agrupacion.Key,
   Trafico = Agrupacion.Count()
};
```

2nd

```
var qTraficoXCategoriaTest1 = registrosDiarios.Where(
q =>( (q.TipoPago_H != GlobalParams.TR_Tipo_Pago_Homologado_Evasor)
&& (q.TipoCliente_H != GlobalParams.TR_Tipo_Cliente_Homologado_Evasor)
&& (q.TipoPago_H != GlobalParams.TR_Tipo_Pago_Homologado_Exento) ))
.GroupBy(o => o.Categoria_H)
.Select(g => new { CodigoCategoria = g.Key, Trafico = g.Count() });
```

The result in the SQL query is

```
╔══════════╦═══════╗
║ Category ║ Count ║
╠══════════╬═══════╣
║ C1       ║  5269 ║
║ C2       ║    82 ║
║ C3       ║   106 ║
║ C4       ║    41 ║
║ C5       ║    47 ║
║ C6       ║    85 ║
║ CE_EG    ║     5 ║
║ CE_IE    ║     2 ║
╚══════════╩═══════╝
```

and this the result in the linq query

```
╔══════════╦═══════╗
║ Category ║ Count ║
╠══════════╬═══════╣
║ C1       ║  5268 ║ * Error
║ C2       ║    82 ║
║ C3       ║   106 ║
║ C4       ║    41 ║
║ C5       ║    47 ║
║ C6       ║    84 ║ * Error
║ CE_EG    ║     5 ║
║ CE_IE    ║     2 ║
╚══════════╩═══════╝
```

The categories C1 and C6 having and error in count when linq runs it.

I appreciate any ideas or contributions that can help me resolve this error.

Comment: You probably have record with space at the end: `SELECT * FROM TR_Movimientos WHERE RIGHT(TipoPago_H,1) = ' ' OR RIGHT(TipoCliente_H,1) = ' ')`

Comment: Thx, i will do a Trim in the values of the linq query.

Comment: Hi, there was a filter and the source collection "registrosDiarios". I remove the filter and works. Thx for your help.